# Documentation feeds

Tags: feature-request, documentation, chat, rss

It would be nice if Documentation would have RSS feeds that we could consume in SE chatrooms. I for one, would definitely add a feed for requested [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) topics in the VBA-dedicated chatroom I own.

Comment: Or is there a way to set up notifications for documentation activity?

Comment: In the tag dashboard look for the eye.

Comment: @Braiam ah, nice! ...though a RSS feed for SE chat would be awesome too IMO.

Comment: I’m working on a chatbot for this. Can’t guarantee anything though.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for this one. I created a other meta about this but deleted it when I realized it was a duplicate.

RSS Feed would be really nice! Would be goot with atleast 2 different feeds for each section/language. One feed for new topics and one feed for topics recently updated/changed. To be able to get updates on both new thing that are added and old things that are being changed.